# Remove Leading from the first Paragraph on every page itext 7 java

Tags: java, itext7

I need to remove Leading property in first Paragrapg on every page(FixedLeading)?

```
     PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    setGridForFirstPage(pdf);
    document.setMargins(0, 25, 25, 25);
    String line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
    Paragraph el = new Paragraph(line);
    Div div = new Div();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        Paragraph element = new Paragraph();
        element.add(line + " " + i);
        element.setFixedLeading(130);
        div.add(element);
    }
    LayoutResult result = div.createRendererSubTree().setParent(document.getRenderer()).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, document.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize())));
    LayoutResult savePageResult = null;
    deleteProperties(result);
    savePageResult = div.createRendererSubTree().setParent(document.getRenderer()).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, document.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize())));
    LayoutResult nextPageResult = savePageResult.getOverflowRenderer().layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(3, document.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize())));
    deleteProperties(nextPageResult);
    document.add(div);
    document.close();

}

private static void deleteProperties(LayoutResult childRendererListParagraph) {
    List<IRenderer> childRenderers = childRendererListParagraph.getSplitRenderer().getChildRenderers();
    for (int j = 0; j < childRenderers.size(); j++) {
        IRenderer iRendererList = childRenderers.get(j);
        if (j == 0) {
            if (iRendererList != null && iRendererList.getModelElement().hasProperty(33)) {
                iRendererList.getModelElement().deleteOwnProperty(33);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its works only two page, i try using a loop, but it didn't work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems plausible: I imagine it could be improved by looping through all the overflow renderers (perhaphs, I will try it out and update the answer someday).

However, there is quite a different approach, which for me seems to be more convenient and accurate: why not to override `ParagraphRenderer`, so that leading is reset each time the corresponding `Paragraph` can not fit a page (and hence will be moved to the next page).

This is how such an extension class may look:

```
    class CustomParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {
    public CustomParagraphRenderer(Paragraph modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        LayoutResult result = super.layout(layoutContext);
        if (result.getStatus() != LayoutResult.FULL) {
            if (null != result.getOverflowRenderer()) {
                result.getOverflowRenderer().setProperty(
                        Property.LEADING,
                        result.getOverflowRenderer().getModelElement().getDefaultProperty(Property.LEADING));
            } else {
                // if overflow renderer is null, that could mean that the whole renderer will overflow
                setProperty(
                        Property.LEADING,
                        result.getOverflowRenderer().getModelElement().getDefaultProperty(Property.LEADING));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    // If not overriden, the default renderer will be used for the overflown part of the corresponding paragraph
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomParagraphRenderer((Paragraph) this.getModelElement());
    }
}
```

Some points which I want to emphasize:

- one should always override `getNextRenderer` in such cases, otherwise the default renderer will be used for the overflown part
- it is better not to update the properties of the model element as you do, since in case you want to reuse the pararaph the initial properties will have been already gone. On the contrary, one should update the properties of the renderer itself (its properties have priority over the model element's, i.e. the paragraph's, ones)

And this is how you can use such a class. The only differences from your code are that:

- `setNextRenderer` is called, so that your paragraph gets asociated with a custom renderer
- leading for the first element is not set

  ```
   doc.setMargins(0, 25, 25, 25);
   String line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
   Div div = new Div();
   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
       Paragraph element = new Paragraph();
       element.setNextRenderer(new CustomParagraphRenderer(element));
       element.add(line + " " + i);
       if (0 != i) {
           element.setFixedLeading(130);
       }
       div.add(element);
   }
  ```

And this is how the resultant PDF looks:
[image]